# How can I perform this following query?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following columns(is_featured, sort, created_at). The maximum featured items is 8 ordered by sort ascending. If the featured item is less than 8, get from the latest nonfeatured item.

```
| id | message | is_featured | sort | created_at |
|----|---------|-------------|------|------------|
| 1  | ...     | 1           | 1    | 2021-06-07 |
| 2  | ...     | 1           | 2    | 2021-06-08 |
| 3  | ...     | 1           | 3    | 2021-06-09 |
| 4  | ...     | 1           | 4    | 2021-06-10 |
| 5  | ...     | 1           | 5    | 2021-06-11 |
| 6  | ...     | 0           | 0    | 2021-06-12 |
| 7  | ...     | 0           | 0    | 2021-06-13 |
| 8  | ...     | 0           | 0    | 2021-06-14 |
```

Here's what I tried so far.

```
$stories = Story::where(function($query) {
    $query->where('is_featured', 0)
        ->latest();
    })->orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where('is_featured', 1)
            ->orderBy('sort', 'asc');
    })->limit(8)
    ->get();
```

I can't wrap my head around this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do this as two queries and merge to resulting collections given the criteria.

```
$featuredStories = Story::where('is_featured', 1)
    ->orderBy('sort', 'asc')
    ->limit(8)
    ->get();

if ($featuredStories->count < 8) {
    $nonFeaturedCount = 8 - $featuredStories->count;
    $nonFeaturedStories = Story::where('is_featured', 0)
        ->limit($nonFeaturedCount)
        ->get();
    $stories = $featuredStories->merge($nonFeaturedStories);
} else {
    $stories = $featuredStories;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. I never knew you can merge queries like that. I accepted your answer cause it works as expected. Thank you for your time.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know either, but Google is handy and now we both know you can merge Eloquent Collections :)

Comment: @Willwalsh your honesty is neat.. And yes.. Google is VERY handy lol